# Git, manually "press any key to continue" I got exit 0. Remove @pause to run automation. Return to exit status 1

Tags: powershell, gitlab

The.ps1 script needs to be executed. I tried setting the `@pause` to proceed, but I had to press any key while the execution was running, and my exit status was 0. I removed the `& @pause` to execute in the git and GitLab pipelines, but the exit status was 1.

Command to execute: `powershell.exe ./build_mech.ps1`

`build_mech.ps1` script:

```
$process = Start-Process "$env:comspec" -WorkingDirectory $cmakeFolder -ArgumentList "/c $envSetup & dir & cmake -G Ninja -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../sparty/opencv_contrib/modules -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .. & cmake --build . & @pause" -PassThru;
$process.WaitForExit();
Write-Output "Mech Result = $($process.ExitCode)";
```

This manually prompts a window that says "press any key to continue", and I got exit status 0. When I run it without pressing any key (by removing `& @pause` in the `build_mech.ps1` script) I'm getting exit status 1.

How can I get an exit status of 0?

Answer (score 0):

Pipe an empty `echo` into the command that needs a return like that:

```
echo | commandthatneedsreturn
```